# Install turtelbot simulator on mac os?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to install turtlebot on mac os ?
I have tried to complie the source from github and when I run rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y
I get

```
the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
kobuki_ftdi: No definition of [ftdi-eeprom] for OS [osx]
kobuki_qtestsuite: No definition of [pyqt4-dev-tools] for OS [osx]
```

Any ideas ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89831/install-turtelbot-simulator-on-mac-os-?/) by [schitic](https://answers.ros.org/users/7656/schitic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is telling you that it doesn't know how to install two required system dependencies because they don't have rosdep keys for OSX.

If you can figure out how to install these dependencies with homebrew or pip, you can fork [rosdistro](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro), add the keys, and submit a pull request.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0